# problem while creating table from maven spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am not able to auto-create table from maven spring mvc.

I was doing a spring mvc project using maven. By far i have got no errors but when i am trying to create table in my database using applicationconfig.xml it is not working. i have searched over the internet but my applicationconfig.xml seems fine to me. I have got no errors. Still the table is not created..

**applicationconfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.milan.entities" /><!--scans model/entity/domain(name 3 but same) and registers-->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventorymanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>       
</beans>
```

**User Class**

```
package com.milan.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

public class User implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long userId;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name = "IS_ENABLEd")
private boolean isEnabled;

public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean isIsEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}

public void setIsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}
}
```

**There is no error while running the program however the table is not created automatically.**

Comment: FYI Spring MVC does not create tables. A JPA provider creates tables.

Answer (score 2):

Put `@Entity` on your User class, if the table still not created try putting below annotations on the class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
```

Could be happening because User is a reserve word in DB.

Comment: Thank You.. That was a silly Mistake..  Problem solved after adding @Entity